# iCalcreator to get Facebook events, for saving to MySQL

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm trying to load a ical upcoming Facebook events feed.
I use iCalcreator with composer, and this is my PHP file:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); 
$v = new vcalendar();
$v->setConfig('url', 'http://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=..&key=..');
$v->parse();
$v->sort();
while( $comp = $v->getComponent()) {
print_r($comp);
}
```

I don't get any errors, but also no output.
How can I retreive the events, so that I can save it in a MySQL database.

I also want to sync the events, like for instance every day.